# Link 4 cells from different TableViewController with a single ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have 4 TableViewControllers inside of a TabBarController(Swift 3) and I want to select a cell from each TableViewController to be displayed in a single ViewController. That is I want a single ViewController to display the 4 selected cells(one for each TableViewController). Thanking your advice

Comment: Where is the problem? You can just load 4 cells inside the ViewController through a TableView. Can't you?

Comment: The problem is that the view controller only gets one cell. It does not cath the others three.

Answer (score 0):

The datasource you are using in 4 `UITableViewController` i.e. Arrays or Dictionaries should be stored in a `SharedInstance` accessible anywhere in `UITabBarController`, more importantly accessible to your desired `UIViewController`.

You can then access the data from each of the datasource and display it in a Cell in your desired `UIViewController`.

There are many ways to do it, this is one. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you: I am trying that